# Make dynamically allocated object type string

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, stdstring

I need to make dynamically allocated object type of string to store sentences and after that sentences should be sorted in alphabetical order using `std::sort`.

This would be correct solution using char array:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
int main() {
  std::cout << "How many senteces: ";
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
  char ** sentence = nullptr;
  std::cout << "Enter senteces:" << std::endl;
  try {
    sentence = new char * [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      sentence[i] = nullptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      char temp[1000];
      std::cin.getline(temp, 1000);
      sentence[i] = new char[strlen(temp) + 1];
      strcpy(sentence[i], temp);
    }
    std::sort(sentence, sentence + n, [](const char * a,
      const char * b) {
      return std::strcmp(a, b) < 0;
    });
    std::cout << "Sorted sentences:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      std::cout << sentence[i] << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      delete[] sentence[i];
    delete[] sentence;
  } catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Problems with memory!";
    return 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I try to convert this to dynamically allocated array type of string, like this:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
  std::cout << "How many senteces: ";
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
  std::string ** sentence = nullptr;
  std::cout << "Enter senteces:" << std::endl;
  try {
    sentence = new std::string * [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      sentence[i] = nullptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      std::string temp;
      std::getline(std::cin, temp);
      sentence[i] = new std::string[temp.length() + 1];
      temp = sentence[i];
    }
    std::sort(sentence, sentence + n, [](std::string a,
      std::string b) {
      for (char & c: a) c = std::toupper(c);
      for (char & c: b) c = std::toupper(c);
      return a < b;
    });
    std::cout << "Sorted sentences:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      std::cout << sentence[i] << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      delete[] sentence[i];
    delete[] sentence;
  } catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Problems with memory!";
    return 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I get a bunch of errors. Could you explain me how to convert this program of dynamically allocation of char array to dynamically allocated string array on a correct way?

Comment: I don't understand why you have a `std::string**` - and I get the feeling you don't know either? You seem to want an array of `std::string`, so at most it should be a `std::string*` (although that still leaves the question why you aren't using an `std::vector<std::string>`)

Comment: Recommendation: Don't use pointers to `string`s and don't dynamically allocate `string`s unless you're forced to by some really rare circumstances. A large part of `string`'s job is to hide both sorts of messiness from you.

Comment: the task is to use string

Comment: could you post the whole code? this confuses me so much... I tried `std::string* sentence = nullptr;` but I still get errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you think `std::string` "corresponds to" `char`, but it corresponds to `char*`.
You want `std::string* sentence = nullptr;`.
(A lot of the point of this exercise is to notice how much easier it gets when you don't need to allocate the strings yourself.)

```
int main() {
  try {
    std::cout << "How many sentences: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    std::cout << "Enter sentences:" << std::endl;
    std::string* sentence = new std::string [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      std::getline(std::cin, sentence[i]);
    }
    std::sort(sentence, sentence + n, [](std::string a,
      std::string b) {
      for (char & c: a) c = std::toupper(c);
      for (char & c: b) c = std::toupper(c);
      return a < b;
    });
    std::cout << "Sorted sentences:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      std::cout << sentence[i] << std::endl;
    delete[] sentence;
  } catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Problems with memory!";
  }
}
```

Comment: would be even better with vector

Comment: Side note/future improvement: rather than continually re-`toupper`ing the `string`s it's probably worth burning some RAM on copies and doing it once before sorting based on the upper-cased copies.